# Angular 5 hostbinding component error when importing into a page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular5

I have one folder contains my custom component page, the structure is:

```
show-hide-password
  |-- show-hide-container.ts
  |-- show-hide-input.ts
  |-- show-hide-password.html
  |-- show-hide-password.scss
component.module.ts
```

Here is my `show-hide-container.ts` looks like:

```
import { Component, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ShowHideInput } from './show-hide-input'

@Component({
  selector: 'show-hide-container',
  templateUrl: 'show-hide-password.html',
  host: {
    'class': 'show-hide-password'
  }
})
export class ShowHideContainer {
  show = false;

  @ContentChild(ShowHideInput) input: ShowHideInput;

  constructor(){}

  toggleShow() {
    this.show = !this.show;
    if (this.show){
      this.input.changeType("text");
    }
    else {
      this.input.changeType("password");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to binding host with second class for my first class component's requirement, the second class component is `show-hide-inputs.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Directive, HostBinding, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[show-hide-input]'
})
export class ShowHideInput {
  @HostBinding() type: string;

  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
    this.type = 'password';
  }

  changeType(type:string) {
    this.type = type;
    this.el.nativeElement.children[0].type = this.type;
  }
}
```

And I'm also add these class components into `components.module.ts` for sharing between component and pages, here is my file:

```
import { ShowHideContainer } from './show-hide-password/show-hide-container';
import { ShowHideInput } from './show-hide-password/show-hide-input';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ShowHideContainer,
        ShowHideInput
    ],
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        ShowHideContainer,
        ShowHideInput
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Next, I'm `adding the component module into app module in the app folder`, also `import component module into selected Ionic pages`, the error is happen here. My selected Ionic page won't able to response shared component, just for example here is my HTML page:

```
<show-hide-container>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" show-hide-input></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</show-hide-container>
```

As can you see, show-hide-container is my shared custom component and ion-input is Ionic default component. The error is:

```
RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'type' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-input'.
1. If 'ion-input' is an Angular component and it has 'type' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-input' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <show-hide-container>
      <ion-item>
        [ERROR ->]<ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" show-hide-input></ion-in"): ng:///SignupPageModule/SignupPage.html@20:8, Directive ShowHideInput
```

Maybe someone could help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to be able to pass a type to your directive, then it should be an input, not a host binding.

Comment: @JBNizet I have solved it by adding NO_ERROR_SCHEMA into every module page.

Comment: That's not a fix. If you don't want to pass a type, then just remove `type="password"` from your ion-input.

Comment: well, I'll follow your suggestion. thank you.